# Can we use Sikuli with PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, automation, phantomjs, sikuli

I want to use Sikuli with PhantomJS.Because web application which we are testing have so many http authenticate pop Ups. We are automating those pop ups by using **Sikuli** when we were using **Selenium**. But now we want to use PhantomJS because user is not able to do any other work while selenium web driver is performing testing on web application. Basically we don't want to block User for doing any other activity. So we are trying to use PhantomJS.

But as we know that PhantomJS is headless browser and Sikuli is image based testing tool . So can we use Sikuli With PhantomJS? If yes, then how can We use it? I know how to use Sikuli with PhantomJS Webdriver?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Add more detailed description. What exactly are you after?

Comment: hi, I edited the question . Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. As you stated *PhantomJS is headless browser and Sikuli is image based testing tool*, so there's no GUI to interact with.

Get some Virtual Machines and run tests on them, so no user is blocked.